# How to create a process with PsProtectedSignerAntimalware flag set if i already have a kernel driver?

Tags: windows, winapi, kernel, driver, wdk

How do some processes in Windows get the PsProtectedSignerAntimalware flag set for them? Meaning how does windows decide which processes should have this flag set when they are created?

More info regarding this flag :

https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/evolution-protected-processes-part-1-pass-hash-mitigations-windows-81/

I doubt that Microsoft has hardcoded the list of AntiViruses somewhere and decides which processes should get this flag based on the certificate, so how does windows decide which processes should get this flag?

**Lets say i already have a driver loaded, is there anyway i can force my user-mode processes to have this flag?**

Comment: if you have a driver, possible found in `EPROCESS` object, where is `PS_PROTECTION` reside, based only on very general assumptions.

Comment: @RbMm yes but obviously modifying the EPROCESS structure is not a really good idea, I don't remember correctly if patchguard catches it or not, but either way there has to be a better and a documented way of doing it

Comment: no, modify `EPROCESS` is ok and good idea. of course patchguard  can not catches this, because `EPROCESS` is volatile by design. this is 100% working and stable solution, which i use in self tools many years

Comment: @RbMm good to know thanks. but how does windows itself decide whether or not to set the PsProtectedSignerAntimalware flag or not?

Comment: this i never research and dont know. probably Ion Larrañaga answer is correct. i by self modify PS_PROTECTION by self inside my process when need and then reset it to 0. usually before open protected process/thread or debug it. and why you need `PsProtectedSignerAntimalware` level ? instead `PsProtectedSignerWinSystem` or `PsProtectedSignerApp`

Comment: @RbMm That's what got confused me as well, Do you think there is any extra protection if you use PsProtectedSignerAntimalware, instead of PsProtectedSignerWinSystem/PsProtectedSignerApp ? or they are equal in terms of protection?

Comment: @RbMm there has to be a difference between them tho, otherwise they wouldn't have made multiple values, But im not sure which one has the highest protection level

Comment: highest binary value - highest level. now, (not look in latest win 10 builds) was `PsProtectedSignerApp = 0x8` highest. possible will be added more. but anyway - 0xf is highest

Comment: @RbMm are you sure that higher always mean more protection?

Comment: yes, of course - higher always mean more protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be related to the EKUs of the certificate used to sign the binary. Take a look at this presentation by Alex Ionescu, at slides 11 and 19:

https://nosuchcon.org/talks/2014/D3_05_Alex_ionescu_Breaking_protected_processes.pdf

And also to the third part of the URL you mentioned:

https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/protected-processes-part-3-windows-pki-internals-signing-levels-scenarios-signers-root-keys/

Anyway, I haven't been able to find the exact value of the EKU that is required, but I think that if you are interested, Microsoft can help you with that.

Comment: you mistake. possible set this from kernel mode. and this not lead to any crash too - no any reason for this.

Comment: Well, that's good to know. I imagined that the kernel would have some kind of protection against this (although in retrospect, even if it has, you are already running in the kernel so you could override even that). I'll remove that part from the answer and leave the rest because I still think it is valid for the question.

Comment: I just share my experience and knowledge + thoughts in this question. *kernel would have some kind of protection against this* - i not think so. based on what ? are it will be periodically check exe, from which process created ? only this way i view. possible but not think. most dangeros here, that format of PS_PROTECTION may change (it already once changed between win7 and win8). but anyway exist reliable way detect this bits place, without any hardcoding , and this work for old (win7) and new format too.

Comment: about *EKU* i not research this, but most likely you are right here

Comment: @IonLarrañaga and i assume there is no way to patch these EKU in the binary itself right? because i remember watching a blackhat presentation, and based on that i think although patching the binary itself would cause the driver to not load anymore, but it was possible to patch some parts of the certificate section?

Comment: I don't think so... In my opinion, you would have to modify your certificate data in the binary and that would make the CA's signature invalid because the hash would no longer match. Maybe they found some vulnerability in the certificate checking process (some recent issue with ECDSA comes to my mind but I don't know if it applies and anyway, using ECDSA for binaries is not common)

Comment: @IonLarrañaga it seems like.. you can tho? this blog post shows adding EKUs to existing certificates, huh!  https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/constraining-extended-key-usages-in-microsoft-windows.aspx

Comment: @OneAndOnly well, I had never seen that section of the certificate management... Still, I'm unsure if you can really add to a leaf certificate an EKU it doesn't have using this tool. Seems to me more like activating or deactivating the EKUs of a leaf certificate by deactivating them in the CA (sort of saying "Hey, I don't want certificates signed by DigiCert to be used for code signing, even if they have the code signing EKU"). Still, it's good to know and I'll take a look at it for sure...

Comment: @IonLarrañaga Alright let me know if you found anything regarding this. Also i found a really good thesis that details many things regarding protected processes and and how to launch them : https://aaltodoc.aalto.fi/bitstream/handle/123456789/38990/master_Aquilino_Broderick_2019.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y